# Trouble saving output contents from a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking to get computers names from my network, so i decided to use this following script :

```
   for /L %%N in (1,1,10) do nslookup 132.147.160.%%N
    PAUSE
```

With this command everything is displaying correctly on the command prompt.

But with this last one not so well :

```
for /L %%N in (1,1,256) do nslookup 132.147.160.%%N >nslookup.txt
PAUSE
```

First of all, the command prompt is displaying wrong things (there's a non-desired "1" added and i don't know why):

```
    C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop>nslookup 132.147.160.1  1>nslookup.txt

C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop>nslookup  132.147.160.2  1>nslookup.txt
*** serveur1.mycompany.fr ne parvient pas à trouver 132.147.160.2 : Non-exi
stent domain

C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop>nslookup  132.147.160.3  1>nslookup.txt
*** serveur1.mycompany.fr ne parvient pas à trouver 132.147.160.3 : Non-exi
stent domain

C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop>nslookup 132.147.160.4  1>nslookup.txt
*** serveur1.mycompany.fr ne parvient pas à trouver 132.147.160.4 : Non-exi
stent domain
[ ... etc]
```

And also in `nslookup.txt`

i've got **NO MORE THAN** this output :

```
Serveur :   serveur1.mycompany.fr
Address:  132.147.160.1

Nom :    132.147.160.256
Address:  60.200.60.100
```

Please, what am i doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: What Windows version? And what should `-A` do?

Comment: Hello, it's on Windows 8. in "nslookup help" section, "-a" mean " conical list of names and aliases (i just tried to translate this in english).
I tried the batch command without the -a, i've got the same weird "1" in the batch command results.

Comment: your nslookup means `Option non valide : A` ?

Comment: In english it means "Invalid option : A", so right now let's say we forget it. 
With "nslookup" only i am able to get the results that i'm looking for. But when i'm looking to saving the output results in a file it doesn't work, and i get the same error above.

Comment: But `Non-existent domain` is not an error, it means, the IP is "empty".

Comment: Yes i get that, but why does i don't have the complete outuput in my txt file ? And why does the command prompt added a "1" after the IP ? Actualy it's saying that ALL OF MY IP is a non-existent domain (whereas without ">afile.txt" a lot of them are not)

Comment: You don't have "1" in your output. Do you need all the error messages in the log file?

Comment: Yes, but I don't get the corect output.

Comment: Yes it would be a good start, maybe i'd be able get the correct output after.

Comment: Actualy I think there's a problem in the command itself, this is why the output it's not correct.

Comment: No, output looks good. Did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /L %%N in (1,1,10) do nslookup 132.147.160.%%N >>nslookup.txt 2>&1
TYPE nslookup.txt
```

To remove the error messages from `nslookup.txt`, simply delete `2>&1`.

Comment: It works like a charm ! Thank you very much ! I'll take a look on google of the little command that you added. Thanks again and have a nice day ! :)